# MeteorJS + npm: Cannot find module 'node-xmpp'

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, node-xmpp

I followed this guide on http://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor.html on how to use npm packages with meteor.  Now I have this

packages.json

```
{
"node-xmpp": "0.10.0"
}
```

server.js

```
var xmpp = Npm.require('node-xmpp');
```

.meteor/packages

```
standard-app-packages
accounts-ui
accounts-github
insecure
accounts-base
accounts-password
npm
```

But I keep getting this when I run the server
W20

```
140608-11:58:32.132(-4)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module 'node-xmpp'
W20140608-11:58:32.132(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
W20140608-11:58:32.132(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
W20140608-11:58:32.132(-4)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
W20140608-11:58:32.132(-4)? (STDERR)     at require (module.js:380:17)
```

Any ideas?

@ChristianFritz, Running npm install node-xmpp from the app's root directory creates \node_modules. When I run the server, meteor explodes, because it thinks they are regular application files.

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
node_modules/node-xmpp/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/insert-module-globals/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/insert-module-globals/node_modules/lexical-scope/node_modules/astw/node_modules/esprima-six/demo/collector.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
```

Comment: did you `npm install node-xmpp`?

Comment: @ChristianFritz this is probably a bad advice, `npm install x` is exactly what you don't want to do here

Comment: @imslavko: why? because he's using the `npm` package, which should install the dependencies automatically?

Comment: @ChristianFritz that's just wouldn't work in the Meteor-land

Comment: http://meteorpedia.com/read/npm

Comment: @imslavko of course it works in meteor, I use manually installed npm packages all the time. Yes, as the page you link says, sometimes you need to still wrap things in a fiber, but that's not a show stopper.

Comment: @ChristianFritz, the comments made my code look like crap.  I am updating the question.

Comment: You need to `npm install` either in a super-directory of the project directory, or just globally, using the `-g` option.

Answer (score 0):

Use Meteor.require() instead of Npm.require().

```
var xmpp = Meteor.require('node-xmpp');
```

Explanation found in the npm package doc (http://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor.html) :

> Normally you are loading core npm modules using Npm.require(), But in order to load modules from your packages.json you need to use Meteor.require()

Comment: Meteor.require() is not working for me either. I had to use `Npm.require('node-xmpp')`.

Comment: Did meteor prove to be a successful framework for pushing XMPP data to the browser?